# Is it possible to have such nesting of functions?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Let $M$ be a countable transitive model of $\sf ZF$, Let $V_\alpha, V_{\alpha+1}$ be two stages of the cumulative hierarchy in $M$, let $f: V_\alpha \to V_{\alpha+1}$ be a bijection such that for any set $S \in V_{\alpha+2}$ we have both $f[S] \in M ; f^{-1}[S] \in M$ .  Let $F: V_{\alpha+1} \to V_{\alpha+2}; F(x)=f[x]=\{f(y) \mid y \in x\}$.

> Is there a proof that we may have a set $S \in V_{\alpha+3}$ such that we don't have both $F[S] \in M; F^{-1}[S] \in M$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have an answer to this question of mine. if $M$ in the question satisfy $AC$, then there must exist some set $S$ in $V_{\alpha+3}$ that doesn't have both $F[S]; F^{-1}[S]$ being elements of $M$, otherwise we can interpret $\sf NF+AC$ which is inconsistent. However, the proof of that result is long.